# sed in AIX script do not work with special chars

Tags: unix, sed, sh, aix

I created a script that is generating HTML code.
At the end of the script, I need to hightlight some words in a table by making them bold.

So I need to replace in the code, every instance of
WORD
by
**WORD**
or
WORD

of course, WORD is stored in a variable $CODE to make this much more harder.

I tryed to used the sed command unfortunatelly with no success.

```
 sed -e 's/$CODE/<b>$CODE</b>/g' page.html > newpage.html
```

I tryed also with double quotes, with escape chars before the /, many combination of quotes and double quotes, with | as delimiter, always with no success.
If any one of you could point me to a solution, I would be really greatfull.

PS : Tryed also with awk ... but with variable it's a real pain in the ...

**EDIT : Here is my exact code to help all of you.** code_list.txt contain a list of CODE-description lines.

```
 for y in code_list.txt
 do
      CODE=$(echo $y | cut -f1 -d-)
      awk -v code="$CODE" '{if(match($0,code)){gsub(code,"<b>"code"</b>")}} 1' $SCRIPTS/html/daily_running_jobs.html > $SCRIPTS/html/daily_running_jobs_highlight.html
      mv $SCRIPTS/html/daily_running_jobs_highlight.html $SCRIPTS/html/daily_running_jobs.html  
 done
```

B²

Comment: small precision, if I echo the command, variables are well translated. But command not executed.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. Include those use cases you think it'll be hard to handle, and if your "WORD"s can include any non-alphabetic characters then describe+show those cases too. Also include cases like 'the' and 'There` so we can see how to handle partial and case-sensitive matching. Finally - don't use all-upper-case for non-exported variable names to avoid clashes with builtin and other exported variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason your idea would not work if

- you use " instead of '
- there is no `@` (**EDIT: and no linebreak**) in the $CODE expression (replace `/` by `@`)

`sed -e "s@$CODE@<b>$CODE</b>@g" page.html > newpage.html`

The problem with your solution was the quoting, and that the sed regex separator `/` was also used **in your replacement expression** as in `</b>`

**EDIT - multiple values to be replaced from file**

If you have a file code_list.txt where all strings-to-be-replaced are in one-per-line, do

```
cp page.html  newpage.html
while read var
do
    mv newpage.html newpage1.html
    sed -e "s@$var@<b>$var</b>@g" newpage1.html > newpage.html
    # optionally rm newpage1.html
done < code_list.txt
```

Comment: I will give it another try, but I think I already tryed this with | instead of @. I'll tell you more tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry Stefan, but it's not working. I have that error message. Variable CODE was replaced by NTCA : sed: Function s@NTCA cannot be parsed.

Comment: From you comment to Chet's answer I suppose that your variable CODE does not contain "NTCA" but "NTCA EBXL FSRV" and possibly even a NEWLINE char somewhere in there - can you please verify if this is intended or if the code is supposed to work if only "NTBA" with nothing after is the value of $CODE - please report the output of `echo ">>$CODE<<"`. In the case you need to replace a string with a newline we possibly have to think about something completely different....

Comment: My replace command is located in a << for CODE in code_list.txt >> loop where code_list.txt contain one code per line. So I assume that it should use the first line code, then do the awk sed command, then the second code and etc.

Comment: how come you are "assuming" it? I think it won't do by itself, you have to code a loop around - see my edit - if would have been easier if you had specified this in the original question

Comment: Sorry , should have read your complete comment before going on - but `for CODE in code_list.txt` would only process the value `code_list.txt`

Comment: Sorry again Stefan but it is still not working. I echoed the command to check, and the var is well replaced by the codes, but the sed command is not executed. I had to remove the -i as it is not supported on my system. I used a > output.html to write the sed output in another file. With no more success.

Comment: ok, if -i is not working we have a problem because each run will overwrite the previous output file and you will end up only with the last replacement being present in the output.html -I'll edit again

Comment: Thank you Stefan, how could I have missed that I'm always updating the same file. I added the file swaping, but unfortunately, the sed command is still not executed :-(

Comment: My bad Stefan. It's working like a charm ! I was looking the wrong html file :-) Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -vcode="$CODE" '{if(match($0,code)){gsub(code,"<b>"code"</b>")}} 1' page.html > newpage.html
```

assume there is a variable **$CODE**

We pass it to awk variable, if there is a match then replace

Comment: Thank you Chet. I'll try this on monday @work.

Comment: awk is not C: `'match($0,code){gsub(code,"<b>"code"</b>")} 1'` but that will fail given various values of `code`, just like an equivalent sed script would, so idk if it's the right answer. Also, by not putting a space between `-v` and `code` you make the script unnecessarily gawk-specific, just put a space in so it's portable: `-v code=...`

Comment: Hi, I just tryed the awk option, but it's not working better : #highlight the important application codes
     for y in $(cat $SCRIPTS/$APP)
     do
          CODE=$(echo $y | cut -f1 -d-)
          awk -v code="$CODE" '{if(match($0,code)){gsub(code,"<b>"code"</b>")}} 1' $SCRIPTS/html/daily_running_jobs.html > $SCRIPTS/html/daily_running_jobs_highlight.html
     done

Comment: It give me that error : + awk -v code=NTCA
EBXL
FSRV {if(match($0,code)){gsub(code,"<b>"code"</b>")}} 1 /home/ppcm980x/ctm_em/etc/emweb/tomcat/webapps/commvault/scripts/html/daily\
_running_jobs.html
+ 1> /home/ppcm980x/ctm_em/etc/emweb/tomcat/webapps/commvault/scripts/html/daily_running_jobs_highlight.html
 awk: String NTCA cannot contain a newline character.
 The source line is 1.
 The error context is
   >>>  <<< 
 awk: String NTCAEBXL cannot contain a newline character.
 The source line is 1.
 awk: String NTCAEBXLEG cannot contain a newline character.
 The source line is 1.

Comment: I have to precide that if I hard code a value in -v code="TEST", then it's working. But using a variable here do not work.