# sed replace using shell variables

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm on Linux Mint 17

I got this command looking at other sed questions on here, but can't seem to get it to work.  Can anyone suggest what is wrong here?  This seems pretty simple but won't work:

`$ cat t |  sed "s/${FSTAB_UUID}/${SWAP_UUID}/"`

> > sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command

`$ echo $FSTAB_UUID`

> > 15542fac-468c-405f-a156-dd781ece7568

`$ echo $SWAP_UUID`

> > 2891fb61-26c3-4606-b310-6c12e4788db5

`$ cat t`

```
UUID=accbd859-7cdd-4d00-86ea-2b5d7d1cee75 /     ext4  errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=15542fac-468c-405f-a156-dd781ece7568 none  swap  rw 0 0
```

Comment: Works as expected with busybox sed.

Comment: OK, I'm on Linux Mint 17

Comment: Also works as expected with GNU sed 4.2.2. What shell are you using?

Comment: please add output of `echo ">>$SWAP_UUID<<"` and `echo ">>$FSTAB_UUID<<"` to see if there is maybe trailing newlines or something in your variables

Comment: @StefanHegny Most likely problem.

Comment: yes,straight reminded me of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632171

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but the `cat` is unnecessary.  `sed` is a filter program that takes a filename as its rightmost argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem by ensuring that the value of `$FSTAB_UUID` starts with a newline (as suggested by @StefanHegny):

> ```
> $ FSTAB_UUID="
> > 15542fac-468c-405f-a156-dd781ece7568"
> $ echo $FSTAB_UUID
> 15542fac-468c-405f-a156-dd781ece7568
> $ echo ">>>$FSTAB_UUID<<<"
> >>>
> 15542fac-468c-405f-a156-dd781ece7568<<<
> $ sed "s/${FSTAB_UUID}/${SWAP_UUID}/" t
> sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command
> ```

(Note that the leading `>` on the second line is a secondary prompt emitted by `bash`; it is not part of the input.)  I see no other explanation for the behavior.

The best solution is to set the values for `$FSTAB_UUID` and `$SWAP_UUID` in a way that does not introduce leading or trailing newlines.  I can't be any more specific, because it's unclear how they are getting in in the first place.

If you can't keep the newlines out, then you also have the option of taking them out after the fact.  This is a bit ugly, but it will remove all leading and trailing whitespace, including newlines, from both values:

```
FSTAB_UUID=${FSTAB_UUID##+([[:space:]])}
FSTAB_UUID=${FSTAB_UUID%%+([[:space:]])}
SWAP_UUID=${SWAP_UUID##+([[:space:]])}
SWAP_UUID=${SWAP_UUID%%+([[:space:]])}
```

The `##` and `%%` inside the parameter expansions tell `bash` to trim the longest prefix or suffix, respectively, that matches the following pattern.  For its part, the pattern matches a string of any positive number of whitespace characters.

Comment: This is correct, I used another awk regex to strip the newline first and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

With your code, I get a similar (only) error on Linux (bash 4.3.11 GNU sed 4.2.2):

```
$ FSTAB_UUID=15542fac-468c-405f-a156-dd781ece7568
$ SWAP_UUID=2891fb61-26c3-4606-b310-6c12e4788db5
$ cat t |  sed "s/${FSTAB_UUID}/${SWAP_UUID}/"
sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 0: pas d'expression régulière précédente
```

(translation: sed: -e expression #1, character 0: no previous regular expression)

But not on FreeBSD (10.2-RELEASE). I can't tell why, and can't find anything explaining this in relation to a difference between GNU sed and classic sed.

Now, on my Linux box, while this may not be the most beautiful workaround, and despite the fact the behaviour *shouldn't* be different from your code, this has yet worked to get the expected result:

```
$ cat t |  sed 's/'"${FSTAB_UUID}"'/'"${SWAP_UUID}"'/'
UUID=accbd859-7cdd-4d00-86ea-2b5d7d1cee75 /     ext4  errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=2891fb61-26c3-4606-b310-6c12e4788db5 none  swap  rw 0 0
$ cat t
UUID=accbd859-7cdd-4d00-86ea-2b5d7d1cee75 /     ext4  errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=15542fac-468c-405f-a156-dd781ece7568 none  swap  rw 0 0
$
```

(just keep the `sed` parts in simple quotes and put the variables between double quotes).

Comment: From my perspective should make absolutely no difference to OP's code

Comment: @StefanHegny I do have an error with his code (see edit #2)

Comment: Is this related to a version problem? Mine is `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: and `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: Error is on Mint 17 BASH 4.3.11 and cygwin BASH 4.3.32